# how to change the loading bar in jquery.reel-1.2-bundle

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the style of a loading bar - how can I do that?
I found that I must change the css in the JS file.
But I couldn't customize my loading bar.
I've do some change yet, but it doesn't work:

```
 va = function(d) {
    D(C + t(Tb) + t(d), {
        position: Sa,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        overflow: jb,
        backgroundImage: url("http://10.200.1.200/bosch_life/life_dev/static/img/layout/loading.png")
        });
        return va["$" + d] = k(T(ra), {
        "class": Tb + C + d
    })
}
```

Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

I can't load your background file, so I can't see what image you are trying to use.

if you just want to change the color, just look in .js file for the first instance of `backgroundColor: '#000'` and replace it with your new color. (The second instance of `backgroundColor` is for the dot indicator if you choose to display the horizontal/vertical indicator.) I'm using the minified version, and it's on line 35.

The full annotated code is https://github.com/pisi/Reel/blob/master/jquery.reel.js
line 1642.

Answer (score 0):

**Height** of the preloader is configurable with Reel option [`preloader`](http://reel360.org/reel#preloader), which takes in a numeric pixel value (`4` is default, `0` to disable preloader progress indication altogether).

The preloader is styled using a CSS stylesheet injected into the head before your stylesheets, so it's very easy to customize just by applying any CSS properties you want to the `.reel-preloader` class in your stylesheet.

*For example to make the preloader red and sticked to the top of the image instead of bottom:*

```
.reel-preloader {
  background: #F00;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Width** of the preloader grows programatically with the percentage progress from 0% to 100%.